# Adjust gridlines in excel PivotChart

Tags: microsoft-excel, charts, pivot-chart

I have the following data:

[image]

Now I create a Pivot Chart which looks like this:

[image: ex]

I add vertical gridlines. However, my problem is that the gridlines are not exactly on the year centered, but the actual value to the corresponding year is in the middle between the gridlines. How can I modify it in that way that the gridlines are centered on the year? So to illustrate it I added some here in red color (of course for each year, I just drew 4):

[image: ex]

I only want these centered, not the grey ones.

In the suggested template options there is one which shows what I want:

[image: ex1]

However, I do not like all the other modifications, I only want to modify the gridlines and furthermore I would like to know how I can do it by myself without a template.

There is an option which changes it (when I click on format axis):

[image: exam]

However, here the space is missing. So I would like to have some space to the left and to the right. Like in the first picture, just with the gridlines centered on the year.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Right click the axis and select both "Add Major Gridlines" and "Add Minor Gridlines":

[image]

You'll have this:

[image]

Right click the Thick lines (Major gridlines) and select 'Format gridlines', then in the Format Gridlines pane, under "Line", select "No line":

[image]

Now repeat the steps to format the minor gridlines, but this time choose 'Solid line' and change the color to whatever color you want:

[image]

The important thing here is that the major gridlines are hiding some of the minor gridlines, so you get the lines where you want them, and you get the slight gap at the beginning and end of the axis.

Comment: Perfect! Thank you.